# Correspondence label and coordinates' points

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinates, subset, matrix-indexing

How to obtain the coordinates of the first and the last appearances (under column-major ordering) of each label present in a matrix?

Example of a label matrix (where labels are `1` to `4`):

```
L = [    
     1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3
     0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
     4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0
    ];
```

For the above example `L`, I would like to obtain a matrix of coordinates like:

```
M = [
    1 1 1
    1 4 1
    2 5 2
    3 7 2
    5 6 3
    6 8 3
    8 1 4
    7 4 4 ];
```

Where the 1<sup>st</sup> column of `M` contains horizontal coordinates, the 2<sup>nd</sup> contains vertical coordinates, and the 3<sup>rd</sup> column contains the label. There should be 2 rows for each label.

Comment: Shouldn't the first row of `M` be `1 1 1` ?

Comment: Yes you right!, I edit

Comment: Also, which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: the version R2015a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With for-loop you can do it like that:

```
M=zeros(2*max(L(:)),3);
for k=1:max(L(:))
   [r,c]=find(L==k);
   s=sortrows([r c],2);
   M(k*2-1:k*2,:)=[s(1,:) k; s(end,:) k];
end

M =
 1     1     1
 1     4     1
 2     5     2
 3     7     2
 5     6     3
 6     8     3
 8     1     4
 7     4     4
```

Maybe somehow with regionprops options you can do it without the loop...

Comment: I totally agree with what you propose  but I do not understand why for some points the matrix comes out to me [255 255 label], the label is good but why 255 for x and y? : -o

Comment: It's ok I find why! I wasn't a double matrix but an uint8 ^^. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a vectorized solution, you can do this:

```
nTags = max(L(:));
whois = bsxfun(@eq,L,reshape(1:nTags,1,1,[]));
% whois = L == reshape(1:nTags,1,1,[]); % >=R2016b syntax.
[X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(whois), find(whois));
tmp = find(diff([0; Z; nTags+1])); tmp = reshape([tmp(1:end-1) tmp(2:end)-1].',[],1);
M = [X(tmp), Y(tmp), repelem(1:nTags,2).'];
```

Or with extreme variable reuse:

```
nTags = max(L(:));
Z = bsxfun(@eq,L,reshape(1:nTags,1,1,[]));
[X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(Z), find(Z));
Z = find(diff([0; Z; nTags+1])); 
Z = reshape([Z(1:end-1) Z(2:end)-1].',[],1);
M = [X(Z), Y(Z), repelem(1:nTags,2).'];
```

---

Here's my benchmarking code:

```
function varargout = b42973322(isGPU,nLabels,lMat)
if nargin < 3
  lMat = 1000;
end
if nargin < 2
  nLabels = 20; % if nLabels > intmax('uint8'), Change the type of L to some other uint.
end
if nargin < 1
  isGPU = false;
end
%% Create L:
if isGPU
  L = sort(gpuArray.randi(nLabels,lMat,lMat,'uint8'),2);
else
  L = sort(randi(nLabels,lMat,lMat,'uint8'),2);
end
%% Equality test:
M{3} = DeviL2(L);
M{2} = DeviL1(L);
M{1} = Adiel(L);
assert(isequal(M{1},M{2},M{3}));
%% Timing:
% t(3) = timeit(@()DeviL2(L)); % This is always slower, so it's irrelevant.
t(2) = timeit(@()DeviL1(L));
t(1) = timeit(@()Adiel(L));
%% Output / Print
if nargout == 0
  disp(t);
else
  varargout{1} = t;  
end

end

function M = Adiel(L)
  M=[];
  for k=1:max(L(:))
     [r,c]=find(L==k);
     s=sortrows([r c],2);
     M=[M;s(1,:) k; s(end,:) k];
  end
end

function M = DeviL1(L)
  nTags = max(L(:));
  whois = L == reshape(1:nTags,1,1,[]); % >=R2016b syntax.
  [X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(whois), find(whois));
  tmp = find(diff([0; Z; nTags+1])); tmp = reshape([tmp(1:end-1) tmp(2:end)-1].',[],1);
  M = [X(tmp), Y(tmp), repelem(1:nTags,2).'];
end

function M = DeviL2(L)
  nTags = max(L(:));
  Z = L == reshape(1:nTags,1,1,[]);
  [X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(Z), find(Z));
  Z = find(diff([0; Z; nTags+1])); 
  Z = reshape([Z(1:end-1) Z(2:end)-1].',[],1);
  M = [X(Z), Y(Z), repelem(1:nTags,2).'];
end
```

Comment: +1 for the creativity! But in addition to the complicate-to-read code, I'm not sure that it's faster... Sometimes `bsxfun` can be terrible in that manner.

Comment: Wow ok I am not used at all to this kind of writing but thank you it will allow me to understand the vectorization :-D. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks guys! @Adiel care to back these claims with a benchmark (with a larger dataset...)? :)

Comment: So, I checked it for L of 800x800, with 20100 different labels. My solution takes 12.03 sec., your first takes 17.64 sec. and your second takes 21.88 sec. Final solutions are identical. So `bsxfun` is beautiful but not always the best way...

Comment: @Adiel I also benchmarked it. The preference is a function of the amount of labels. I tried it on 4000x4000 with 20 labels, and my 2nd method is better by about 30%. That is unless the matrices are `gpuArray`, in which case the loop loses every time (it is slower by x1.3 - x4).

Comment: I sticked to the labels density of the original question, but it makes sense that the method should be chosen depending on the specific case

Answer (score 5):

I just had to try it with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
R = size(L, 1);
[rowIndex, colIndex, values] = find(L);  % Find nonzero values
index = (colIndex-1).*R+rowIndex;        % Create a linear index
labels = unique(values);                 % Find unique values
nLabels = numel(labels);
minmax = zeros(2, nLabels);
minmax(1, :) = accumarray(values, index, [nLabels 1], @min);  % Collect minima
minmax(2, :) = accumarray(values, index, [nLabels 1], @max);  % Collect maxima
temp = ceil(minmax(:)/R);
M = [minmax(:)-R.*(temp-1) temp repelem(labels, 2, 1)];  % Convert index to subscripts

M =

     1     1     1
     1     4     1
     2     5     2
     3     7     2
     5     6     3
     6     8     3
     8     1     4
     7     4     4
```

Here's what I got for timing with [Dev-iL's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42974120/52738) and [Adiel's newest code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42973610/52738) (*Note that the number of labels can't go above 127 due to how Adiel's code uses the `uint8` values as indices*):

```
                       |   Adiel |  Dev-iL | gnovice
-----------------------+---------+---------+---------
  20 labels, 1000x1000 |  0.0753 |  0.0991 |  0.0889
20 labels, 10000x10000 | 12.0010 | 10.2207 |  8.7034
 120 labels, 1000x1000 |  0.1924 |  0.3439 |  0.1387
```

So, for moderate numbers of labels and (relatively) smaller sizes, Adiel's looping solution looks like it does best, with my solution lying between his and Dev-iL's. For larger sizes or greater numbers of labels, my solution starts to take the lead.

Comment: Good job! Vectorization FTW :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive the uniqe values (your *labels*) of the matrix with [`unique`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).

Having them retrived you can use [`find`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get their indices.

Put together your matrix with it.

Comment: With the other three answer providing a total approach, as opposed to this very general guideline, I suggest either to extend this answer to also give a total approach, or removing it altogether if you thinks it would add no value to the question in light of the other answers.